# WebSharper is unable to decode a function parameter of a record type

Tags: f#, websharper

WebSharper **2.5.8-alpha** seems to be unable to process a function with a parameter of a record type.
My code is fairly simple:

```ml
type Foo =
{
    Name: string
    Num: int
}
[<Rpc>]
let Bar (foo: Foo) =
    foo |> ignore

[<JavaScript>]
let Baz =
    Bar { Foo.Name="ABC"; Foo.Num=42 }
```

When WebSharper is processing the assembly, it reports the following error, pointing to `Bar`:

> Cannot decode a parameter from JSON: foo

The official version 2.4.85.235 works absolutely fine.

**Is there any workaround?**

*Note:* I'm trying to use WebSharper 2.5.8-alpha because the official/stable version is suffering from an error described here: [Content.Redirect is a permanent redirect](https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/83/contentredirect-is-a-permanent-redirect).

Comment: For such a version-specific bug, you probably want to use the issue tracker you linked to rather than Stack Overflow, no?

Comment: @Tarmil Absolutely. I'm new to WebSharper, so trying to figure out first if it's not my misunderstanding.

Comment: Try with WebSharper 2.4. It works.

Comment: @ArthurFSharp He did try: `"The official version 2.4.85.235 works absolutely fine."`.

Comment: I just tried this on a 2.5.8 template from http://websharper.apphb.com/ and it works fine. Can you post your whole project that manifests the error? On the issue tracker (https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issues). Thanks.